# RESTful web service url html vs json

Tags: json, node.js, web-services, rest

To generate urls for accessing data for customers, I follow the specification:

1. Deliver all JSON data pertaining to customers at the URL: wwww.somesite.com/customers
2. To create, update or delete, use the www.somesite.com/customers/ url with the appropriate verbs i.e. POST, PUT and DEL respectively

However, I want to provide an html page also (preferably at www.somesite.com/customers) which accesses all the JSON data via AJAX calls.

Should I respond at the same url (www.somesite.com/customers) with HTML or JSON based on the headers in the requests? Or is there a better/standard way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using headers is tricky to work with. Imo it's best just to use a predictably different url for the api. Such as:

- www.somesite.com/customers.json
- api.somesite.com/customers
- www.somesite.com/api/customers
- www.somesite.com/api/v1/customers

Answer (score 1):

As per REST principles the URL indicates the resource and the response is the representation of the resource.

You can generate different representations (JSON or HTML) for the same resource base on client specified criteria. This can be specified through the Accept header item or the Query string.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

You can look inside the request if it's an `xhr-Request` e.g. in express.js it's located at ``req.xhr`. Depend on if it's true you can deliver HTML or JSON.

```
app.get('/customers', function(req, res){
    if(req.xhr){
      res.type('application/json');
      res.send({});
    }else{
      res.type('text/html');
      res.send('<html>...</html>');
    }
});
```